# Displaying R result of summary function in PowerBI

Tags: r, powerbi

I am running some simple commands in R within the PowerBI software:

[image]

However, the results won't show in the PowerBI Dashboard and I keep having this error:

[image]

What is happening and how can I show some simple results of R functions in PowerBI?

Comment: `summary(dataset)` is not a visual. Power BI does not display `summary()` outputs. What is your goal?

Comment: Check out the known limitations in the [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-r-visuals):  `Only plots that are plotted to the R default display device are displayed correctly on the canvas. Avoid explicitly using a different R display device.`

Comment: You have to use any allowed plotting pacakges from R to show visual, It can't just display you the dataset in raw.